# How can I skip the login prompt for Visual Sourcesafe?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I'd like to automatically login to VSS when I open it, and skip the login prompt altogether.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can append the -Y command line switch:

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edy95zhk(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: BTW - You can also use the -S option to specify a different database to connect to - e.g. -SC:\LocalVSSRepository -YLocalUse,LocalPassword

Answer (score 9):

Answering my own question:

1 - Right-click My Computer, click Properties

2 - Click "Advanced" -> "Environment Variables"

3 - Under User variables for , click "New".

4 - Variable name = "SSUSER", Variable Value = < your VSS username >

5 - Repeat steps 3 & 4 for "SSPWD" and < your VSS password >

Answer (score 0):

If your user-login name is the same as your "network" name (in my case, my Windows user name), my experience is that I don't have to be prompted for the log in. My VSS 6.0 server machine has an account for my name, and my VSS 6.0 client machine has the same (non-administrative) account from which I do development.

In the VSS Admin application, look at the Tools | Options | General tab and the check box for "Use network name for automatic user log in".

Of course, this requires cooperation of your administrator and determination of whatever policies there are for VSS user names and log-in security.  In my case, I wear both hats and we get along fine.

As I recall, even though I don't access VSS from the admin account, I have the same arrangement for the admin user-login and I don't seem to have to log in very often when using VSS Admin as well.  (I do that so rarely that I honestly don't remember, but I didn't have to log in when bringing it up just now.)

Comment: This is true at work, but at home, I don't have a domain and this doesn't help.  Thanks though.